# Android: Addview to LinearLayout is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a simple **Scrollview** containing a **LinearLayout** for a translation program.  Using a button, the user should be able to view a series of translations for a given word - This all works as I hoped (maybe not with the most efficient coding but hey?) however when it came to populating the LinearLayout using a series of addviews I couldn't get them to display on screen - I researched a bit and have gone through various attempts of invalidate, postinvalidate, updateviewlayout and refreshdrawablestate without any appearance of the new views in the layout.  My only success came with setcontentview.

**The problem is that** *setcontentview is basically redrawing all the layouts and hence wipes away all my button listeners and the dropdown adapter for the autocompletetextview I am using.  My program becomes a shell with a scrollable list of translated words*.

What I want to be able to do is have the addviews incorporated and then become visible without losing the rest of the programmatical workings of the app. It should remain functional basically, but I'm lost on how to do this.  All the solutions I've tried and listed above are not displaying the addviews at all.

**My OnClickListener code, warts and all:**

```
   private OnClickListener TranslatorListener = new OnClickListener() 
       {
        @Override
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
              int wordpos;
              View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_scubatranslator, null, false);
              ScrollView sb = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.Scroll_Box);
              sb.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_transparent_70));
              LinearLayout scroll_list = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Scroller);
              scroll_list.removeAllViews();

              if (current_word == ""){
                  AutoCompleteTextView source = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.Translator_Search_Box);
                  current_word = source.getText().toString();
              }

              if (Arrays.asList(current_list).contains(current_word)){

                  wordpos = Arrays.asList(current_list).indexOf(current_word);

                  TextView CheckText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
                  CheckText.setText(current_lang + " / " + wordpos + " / " + tracker);

                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                  llp.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);

                  //for (int lc = 1; lc <=lang_count; ++lc){
                  for (int lc = 1; lc <= 19; ++lc){
                      if (tracker == lc){
                      }  
                      else {
                          switch (lc) {
                            case 1: TextView ChineseView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    ChineseView.setText("  " + ChineseList[wordpos]);
                                    ChineseView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    ChineseView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    ChineseView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_1, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    ChineseView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    ChineseView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(ChineseView);
                                    break;
                            case 2: TextView DanishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    DanishView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    DanishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    DanishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    DanishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_2, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    DanishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    DanishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(DanishView);
                                    break;
                            case 3: TextView DutchView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    DutchView.setText("  " + DutchList[wordpos]);
                                    DutchView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    DutchView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    DutchView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_3, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    DutchView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    DutchView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(DutchView);
                                    break;
                            case 4: TextView EnglishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    EnglishView.setText("  " + EnglishList[wordpos]);
                                    EnglishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    EnglishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    EnglishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_4, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    EnglishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    EnglishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(EnglishView);
                                    break;
                            case 5: TextView FilipinoView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    FilipinoView.setText("  " + FilipinoList[wordpos]);
                                    FilipinoView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    FilipinoView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    FilipinoView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_5, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    FilipinoView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    FilipinoView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(FilipinoView);
                                    break;
                            case 6: TextView FinnishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    FinnishView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    FinnishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    FinnishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    FinnishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_6, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    FinnishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    FinnishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(FinnishView);
                                    break;
                            case 7: TextView FrenchView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    FrenchView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    FrenchView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    FrenchView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    FrenchView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_7, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    FrenchView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    FrenchView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(FrenchView);
                                    break;
                            case 8: TextView GermanView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    GermanView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    GermanView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    GermanView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    GermanView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_8, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    GermanView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    GermanView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(GermanView);
                                    break;
                            case 9: TextView ItalianView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    ItalianView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    ItalianView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    ItalianView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    ItalianView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_9, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    ItalianView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    ItalianView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(ItalianView);
                                    break;
                            case 10: TextView JapaneseView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    JapaneseView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    JapaneseView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    JapaneseView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    JapaneseView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_10, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    JapaneseView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    JapaneseView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(JapaneseView);
                                    break;
                            case 11: TextView KoreanView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    KoreanView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    KoreanView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    KoreanView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    KoreanView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_11, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    KoreanView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    KoreanView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(KoreanView);
                                    break;
                            case 12: TextView NorwegianView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    NorwegianView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    NorwegianView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    NorwegianView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    NorwegianView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_12, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    NorwegianView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    NorwegianView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(NorwegianView);
                                    break;
                            case 13: TextView PolishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    PolishView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    PolishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    PolishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    PolishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_13, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    PolishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    PolishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(PolishView);
                                    break;
                            case 14: TextView PortugeseView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    PortugeseView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    PortugeseView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    PortugeseView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    PortugeseView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_14, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    PortugeseView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    PortugeseView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(PortugeseView);
                                    break;
                            case 15: TextView RussianView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    RussianView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    RussianView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    RussianView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    RussianView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_15, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    RussianView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    RussianView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(RussianView);
                                    break;
                            case 16: TextView SpanishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    SpanishView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    SpanishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    SpanishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    SpanishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_16, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    SpanishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    SpanishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(SpanishView);
                                    break;
                            case 17: TextView SwedishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    SwedishView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    SwedishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    SwedishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    SwedishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_17, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    SwedishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    SwedishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(SwedishView);
                                    break;
                            case 18: TextView ThaiView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    ThaiView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    ThaiView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    ThaiView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    ThaiView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_18, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    ThaiView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    ThaiView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(ThaiView);
                                    break;
                            case 19: TextView TurkishView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                    TurkishView.setText("  " + DanishList[wordpos]);
                                    TurkishView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                                    TurkishView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                    TurkishView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.lang_icon_19, 0, 0 , 0 );
                                    TurkishView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                    TurkishView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                                    scroll_list.addView(TurkishView);
                                    break;
                       default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("oops?");
                       }
                     }
                  }     

                  // ScrollView sb = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Scroll_Box);
                  // sb.updateViewLayout(scroll_list); these did not show the addviews

              }  
              else {

                  int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                  String message = getResources().getString(R.string.Trans_Warning);
                  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
                  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                  View toastview = toast.getView();
                  toastview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_transparent_70));
                  toast.show();
              }

              current_word = "";
              // ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.Scroller);
              // vg.invalidate(); 
              // vg.refreshDrawableState ();  these did not show the addviews
              setContentView(view);
          }
       };
```

Thanks for any advice - but go easy I'm an utter rookie programmer - learning as I go...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this to intialize your `TextView`:

```
TextView text = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.include_textview, container, false);
```

Where the `container` is the `LinearLayout` you want to populate.

Comment: But the Textview is dynamically created - it has no r.layout reference.  Will it make a difference referencing a pre-existing layout in the way you suggest instead of dynamically creating them?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dynamically creating", because you can create them dynamically the way I mentioned. I think you are confused about what is dynamic and what is programmatic.

Comment: I can find no reference to R.layout.include_textview anywhere online and eclipse won't accept this method.